# C# Check if two generic variables point to same element

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I have two variables that both have the same generic type `T`. Is there a way to check if both variables point to the same variable?

Eg.: I have a `Person` class and have two independent variables: `Person peter` and `Person jack`. My `T` is set to `Person`. The check I want to do should return `true` if `T variableA` and `T variableB` are both set to `peter` and should return `false` if `T variableA` is set to `peter` and `T variableB` is set to `jack`.

Comment: What if those two variables (`peter` and `jack`) both have values which are references to the same object? Note that other than `ref` variables, a variable doesn't "point to" a variable... a variable of type `T` has a value of type `T`, which (for classes) is a reference to an object of type `T` or a subclass.

Comment: of if `jack` was defined like `var jack = new Person { Name = "Peter" }`? In fact the concept of a variable-*name* does not have **any** meaning in C#. You should never rely on a variable having a specific name.

Comment: Without seeing some code it's really hard to get what exactly you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.ReferenceEquals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals?view=net-6.0)

```
Person peter = new Person{ Name = "Peter" };
Person jack = peter;
bool sameReference = Object.ReferenceEquals(peter, jack); // true
```